# Error importing jar in groovy script (soapui)

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a problem with running java code from groovy script (groovy script is a part of SoapUI test suite)
i create simple script:

```
import myjar.jar
new TopClass().sayHello()
```

the code of TopClass:

```
public class TopClass {
    public void sayHello (){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }   
}
```

I put myjar.jar into both soapui-pro-2.5\lib and soapui-pro-2.5\bin\ext folders.
But running script I get:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed, Script1.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class myjar.jar @
>   line 2, column 1.org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to
>   resolve class myjar.jar @ line 2, column 1. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:113)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:970)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$5.call(CompilationUnit.java:527)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:772)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:438)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
>   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:572) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:584) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:564) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:603) at

Please help me to find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you added the jar to the build path? In Eclipse "addToBuildPath"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the jar under `soapui-pro-2.5\bin\ext` is all you need for the classes to be found (although restarting `SoapUI` won't hurt).

However - you should check that the error you get is related to your jar. Is `com.my.research` available within `myjar.jar`? If no - just add it.

If yes, add more detailed information to your post.

Comment: yes, it available - in fact, that is the only package in jar. According to console myjar is added to classpath:

 [SoapUI] Adding [/opt/soapui-4.5.0/bin/ext/myjar.jar] to extensions classpath . . after script start I get: . . org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script6.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.my.research @ line 1, column 1. import com.my.research

Comment: When you use `import` you can either import a single class `import com.my.research.MyClass` or an entire package `import com.my.research.*` - you seem to have done neither. Try one of those and update us on the result.

Answer (score 1):

import myjar.jar

I believe this is not correct, you should be importing the name of the java package not the name of the jar.
Hope this helps

Comment: the same error(


`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, Script2.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.my.research`

Answer (score 0):

On non-windows implementations of soapui I find it helps if you add it to the .sh file that starts soapui explicitly.